# COPY misses some records

Tags: postgresql, copy

everybody.
I have a problem with usage of COPY function in Postgres. It doesn't insert all records from the file. I have the file with 761269 records in it and the COPY function only copies 610357 records in a database. Moreover, it doesn't fail as the file would contain some records of a bad format. It finishes successfully writting: COPY 610357. What could be the problem?

Comment: *"Nawww... COPY doesn't 'miss' things."* If records can't be inserted for any reason, e.g. because they are bad or because they are duplicate, it might not say a word.  It just doesn't copy them, and it tells you how many it *did* copy.  Annoying, but that's how they wrote the thing.

Comment: Inserting duplicates doesn't violate any rules (at least, according to the documentation). It seems, the case in bad-formatted records. But what surprises me is that COPY checkes some records' format and doesn't check the others' one though these records are located in the one file.

Comment: You might want to consider showing examples of both the source, table structure, and records that fail to copy.

Comment: "Inserting duplicates" *will* "violate the rules" if there are primary-keys, or Unique indexes, or referential-integrity constraints, or ...

Comment: Thanks to everybody. The problem was that some quotes had creeped into my data.